# Snort rule for Java script does not work

Tags: javascript, rule, snort

I do not understand why the following rule does not detect the content "unescape":

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"example 1";flow:to_client,established;file_data;content:"unescape";sid:20001)
```

While the following works:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"example 1";flow:to_client,established;file_data;content:"<script>";sid:20001)
```

It seems that Snort does not detect any content inside script tags.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your question? You seem to already have an answer. . .

Comment: I have to detect "unescape" not "<script>", "<script>" is detected, but "unescape" not. Why ? (obviously the unescape function is inside <script></script> tags. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to nomalize javascript in the http preprocessor.  You need to make sure that you have this enabled otherwise functions like unescape will not be what you expect. however, you should still see "unescape", so I'm not entirely sure this is your problem. You can read about how to configure this option in the snort manual in the [server configuration options](http://manual.snort.org/node17.html#SECTION00327800000000000000).  Here is the snippet from the manual about this option:

"normalize_javascript This option enables the normalization of Javascript within the HTTP response body. You should select the config option extended_response_inspection before configuring this option. When this option is turned on, Http Inspect searches for a Javascript within the HTTP response body by searching for the `<script>` tags and starts normalizing it. When Http Inspect sees the `<script>` tag without a type, it is considered as a javascript. The obfuscated data within the javascript functions such as **unescape**, String.fromCharCode, decodeURI, decodeURIComponent will be normalized. The different encodings handled within the unescape/ decodeURI/decodeURIComponent are %XX, %uXXXX,
XX and
uXXXXi. Apart from these encodings, Http Inspect will also detect the consecutive whitespaces and normalize it to a single space. Http Inspect will also normalize the plus and concatenate the strings. The rule option file_data can be used to access this normalized buffer from the rule. A preprocessor alert with SID 9 and GID 120 is generated when the obfuscation levels within the Http Inspect is equal to or greater than 2."

If this still isn't working then you should check the follow:

It's possible that your server_flow_depth in the [http preprocessor server configuration](http://manual.snort.org/node17.html#SECTION00327400000000000000) configuration is set too low. The default is 300, so If "`<script>`" comes within the first 300 bytes and "unescape" comes after 300 bytes, snort won't inspect that far.  Try setting this value to 65535. You should be able to test this by having a content match for "`</script>`", if this doesn't generate an alert it's likely that setting.

Comment: server_flow_depth is set to 0. The <script> and </script> are both detected and also tags before and after such as <html></html>, but everything inside <script></script> tags is not detected. Thx

Comment: do you have any way of providing a sample pcap of this traffic?

Comment: I do not understand why, but disabling normalize_javascript it works.